# How do I find out if a Property / Field is a Reference Type (using Reflection)

Tags: c#, reflection

I have already checked out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4628395/detecting-if-class-property-is-a-reference-type) link. There was the problem, that generally there was an unexact terminology of "reference". So firstly I want to clarify when *in my opinion* a Type is a reference Type.

This is the behavior of a not reference Type.

```
        string bla = "abc";
        string blob = bla;
        bla = "cde";
        // bla = "cde" and blob = "abc"
```

This is the behavior of a reference Type

```
        Person jens = new Person("Jens");
        Person frank = jens; // doesn't make any sense i know
        frank.Name = "Frank";
        //jens.Name = "Frank" and frank.Name = "Frank"
```

As you can see once you reference only Types pass a Reference (like a Pointer in c). You can also achieve that behavior for nonreference Types by using the **ref** Keyword.

What I am searching for is a Property of the Type Class that indicates whether the type is a reference type or not.

It should also work for structs, simply for everything where you can "store" something in it.

According to the link I provided above there are multiple Properties, all slightly different

- IsClass
- IsPrimitive
- IsValueType

Which one do I need do use?
None of them seems to fit my conditions.

*sorry for my bad english :)*

Comment: Your two methods are doing two different things. In the first one you are assigning a value to `X`,  in the second one You are assigning a value to `X.A` then asking "why didn't the value of `X` change.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain I am assining x = y and then assining y.A just to show that x.A has changed too

Comment: Yes, but you don't do `y.A` for the string version. If the class `String` had property with a public setter you could do the same thing with that. To make the examples equivalent replace `frank.Name = "Frank";` with `jens = new Person("Frank");` and see what the value of frank and jens is. When working with strings pretend just typing `"stuff"` is really doing `new String(new char[] {'s', 't', 'u', 'f', 'f'})` and the behavior you are seeing makes a lot more sense.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain you are right, but in the example above, if used 'int' instead of 'string'? In Fact i just wanted to show the behavior I ment. Im a unexperienced programmer, so please be a bit forgiving with me if im not alwaways 100% accurate writing a question.

Answer (score 1):

`String` is a special built-in type, like `Int32` or `Double`, which has the special property that you can express it as a literal value in C#. Both also happen to be [immutable types](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immutable_object), which I think may be somewhat related to what you're struggling with.

My guess is that you are making some wrong assumptions about what references mean in C#. The words `reference` and `struct` are used in both languages, but their respective meanings are very different.

In your second example, `frank` and `jens` are both references to the *same actual object*. Think of them as both being **pointers to the same address in memory** -- because somewhere in there, they are.

It looks like you believe that when you assign `jens` to `frank`, you are invoking a copy constructor. If `jens` and `frank` were stack variables in C++, that's what would happen. But C# isn't C++. A C# reference is rebindable. As far as assignment is concerned, it is like a *pointer* in C++, not a C++ reference. But unlike C++ pointers, you can't do "pointer arithmetic" with it and you don't need to dereference it.

In C#, when you want to copy an instance of a *reference type* such as `String` or (evidently) `Person`, you need to do that explicitly.

```
//  Assume Person has a Person(String name) constructor
Person bob = new Person("Bob");

//  This assigns a **reference to bob** to a new reference variable.
//  steve and bob are now referencing the same object. Not what you want.
Person steve = bob;

//  Person should have a copy constructor. If that's done correctly, 
//  this will create a COPY of the object that both steve and bob
//  refer to. 
Person bob2 = new Person(steve);

//  Because we explicitly created a new instance for bob2, this won't
//  affect the other "Bob" instance that bob and steve still refer to.
bob2.Name = "Bob Junior";
```

A "non reference" type in C# is called a `struct`. `DateTime` is an example. When copying, a C# `struct` behaves like a C++ class instance on the stack: There's an implicit copy.

```
//  DateTime is a struct. It's IsValueType, NOT IsClass. 
//  Different behavior. 
DateTime today = DateTime.Now.Date;

//  This creates a copy, because DateTime is a struct not a class.
DateTime alsoToday = today;
```

Is this just (laudable) general curiosity about the language, or is there a specific problem you're trying to solve? I often find that when somebody asks "why are you really trying to do this?" the answer allows us to be a lot more helpful than if we focused on the specific technique you're trying to use to solve a problem. A question like this one is usually a hint that the OP picked the wrong solution to begin with.

Comment: I used to learn programing in c with a German language background, so thats why i was struggling with the names. The word *immutability* is new to me. So thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: @LuckyLikey One thing I forgot to mention: What is your actual goal here that you are trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 0):

`IsValueType` is what you are looking for.

Please note: `string` is in fact a reference type.

Comment: string's assigment operator does NOT show value semantics. All string is, is a class with no public setters. It is a immutable object. Nothing fancy about "pretending to be a value type" it is just a read only object that creates **new** read only objects whenever you use a method that returns a string (This includes `operator +`)

Comment: Not only is this answer factually wrong, it also doesn't address the apparent source of OP's confusion.